# View Source functionality using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, output

The feature I'm trying to implement is a toggle view source button so the user can view the source of a given element then copy the text.

Using the ngRoute module, my views are coming through ng-view:

```
<div id="code" ng-view=""></div>
```

I would like the HTML to be output to:

```
<div id="html-text-output"></div>
```

I've tried using the $sanitize function but I'm not sure it is appropriate for my solution. Below is the code currently in my controller:

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('outputHtmlCtrl', function ($scope, $element, $sanitize) {
  $scope.isOutputToggled = true;

  var sanatizedHtml = $sanitize($('#email-frame-code').html());

  $scope.toggleHtmlOutput = function() {            
    $scope.isOutputToggled = $scope.isOutputToggled === false ? true: false;
    $('#html-text-output').append("<div>"+"'"+sanatizedHtml+"'"+"</div>");
  }
});
```

My markup is below:

```
<div id="email-frame-code__container" ng-controller="outputHtmlCtrl">
  <div class="browser-header">
    <span class="browser-header__icon" ng-click="toggleHtmlOutput()"></span>
  </div>

  <div id="email-frame-code" ng-class="{closed: isOutputToggled}">
    <div id="html-text-output"></div>
    <div id="code" ng-view=""></div>
  </div>                
</div>
```

My end goal for this is like the 'Fancy Version' here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewSourceButton/

But on a target element, not the whole page.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a directive.

Comment: you still haven't clarified what exactly needs to be copied.... the html structure? If so you need to put that into a textarea. Inserting html into the dom won't do anything other than duplicate what can already be seen

Comment: wait, so you are trying to get the `.html()` of a `<div>`, save that into a string, then output that string as HTML into an element that is nested inside the original `<div>`?

Comment: All of the code rendered by ng-view will be copied by the user.

Comment: also, I state this frequently, if you are using JQuery `.append` in an angular application, you are probably doing something wrong.  In this case, you can simply use `ng-bind-html` with the `sanatizedHtml` string, and using `$().html()` isn't necessary either, if you are targeting the correct element in the first place.  However, don't expect `$sanitize` to remove angular statements, elements, etc.